# flutter downloader is not downloading file

Tags: flutter

i am using flutter downloader package to download file.Bit it is not downloading file,it says download failed is  phone status bar.I have tried with both local and online file.
I have provided the mainfest code and my code logic to download the files.
here is my code:

```
     String url = "D:/flutter/income_and_expenditure/income_and_expenditure_app/asset/logo.png";
  Tween<Offset> offset =
      Tween(begin: const Offset(1, 0), end: const Offset(0, 0));
  @override
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    // if (controller.todayIncome.isEmpty || ) {
    //   controller.getTodayIncomeExpense('income');
    // }
    // controller.getGroupByData('expense');
    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(receivePort.sendPort, "download");
    receivePort.listen((message) {
      print(message.progress);
    });
    FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallBack);
    super.initState();
  }

  void downloadFile(String url) async {
    final status = await Permission.storage.request();
    if (status.isGranted) {
      final baseStorage = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      final id = FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
          url: url,
          savedDir: baseStorage!.path,
          fileName: "${DateTime.now()}download",
          openFileFromNotification: true,
          showNotification: true);
    }
  }

  static downloadCallBack(id, status, progress) {
    SendPort? sendport = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName("download");
    sendport?.send(progress);
  }
```

and my mainfest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
   
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <application
        android:label="income_and_expenditure_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
    android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

in debug console:

```
W/System.err(21961): java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: d
W/System.err(21961):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:608)
W/System.err(21961):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:498)
W/System.err(21961):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:447)
W/System.err(21961):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.downloadFile(DownloadWorker.kt:291)
W/System.err(21961):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.doWork(DownloadWorker.kt:206)
W/System.err(21961):    at androidx.work.Worker$1.run(Worker.java:86)
W/System.err(21961):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err(21961):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err(21961):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(21961): Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=72cea381-13ab-4d1b-bcf9-35fff38b703a, tags={ flutter_download_task, vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker } ]
```

Comment: Now it is working after i restart my emulator